# Could not map json for Realm DB

Tags: android, parsing, realm, json

I wanna create some Objects in my Realm using "realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(type.class, json-array)". But it throws error -> could not map json.

Heres the Json-Array. It's valid.

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "99975b79-adac-4baa-a1ab-96c0db23c0ee",
        "name": "Joris"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "0",
        "name": "Adrian"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "0",
        "name": "Oliver"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "0",
        "name": "Michael"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "0",
        "name": "David"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "0",
        "name": "Daniel"
    }
]
```

and heres my Owner-Model.

```
public class Owner extends RealmObject{

@PrimaryKey
private String      uuid; //PK
private String      name;
private String      token;
private RealmList<Idea> ideas;
private RealmList<Vote> votes;
```

Here's the code where the error is thrown. its in the 3. line

```
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Tag.class, tagJson);
    realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Owner.class, ownerJson);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

it's strange how the creating of Tag-Objects works fine..
please help!!

greetings john

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You UUID is marked as a `@PrimaryKey` and you have multiple "uuid"'s with the value `0`. This means that you are breaking the primary key constraint of only having one element with each uuid. If you look closely in LogCat you will probably see that `Could not map JSON` exception mentions this as well.

Comment: oh. i shouldn't work when im tired. hehe..
thanks for your help. I'll keep that in mind.